# setup Orbit vertically in Foundation?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation

I have orbit working fine horizontally. Code below:

```
<div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns">
        <ul data-orbit>
            <li>
                <img src="./img/projects_img1.png" alt="slide 1" />
            </li>
            <li class="active">
                <img src="./img/projects_img2.png" alt="slide 2" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Following is the script I have.

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.orbit.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).foundation({
  orbit: {
    animation: 'slide',

    navigation_arrows: true,

    next_on_click: true,




}
});

</script>
```

It works fine for sliding images left-right or right-left. But I want the image to slide top-bottom (vertically) on click . 
Is there a way to do this? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What about making a fiddle?

Comment: I have no idea how fiddle works or anything on fiddle ! I will have a look. It would be nice if I could use in foundation itself.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/tutorial.html